# jdbc exception after jar creation

Tags: java, jdbc, jar, manifest

I've got an application, where I use a JDBC connection. When I run it from the Eclipse environment, there's no problem.
But, when I pack it into jar, the line

```
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
```

causes an exception:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
```

I put a line into manifest file, but it didn't help:

```
Class-Path: sqljdbc4.jar
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: try adding it separately to classpath

Comment: Where are the two jars located in the filesystem, and how do you start the application?

Comment: Now I put the sqljdbc.jar file to the application's folder and there's no more exception.
However, after calling the

    `DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);`

the application is frozen.
I run it by using a batch file, which contains:

    `java -jar myapp.jar`

Comment: Not enough info to tell, but the first thing that I'd look at is to make sure that the url is correct, that the jar file is the correct version for your version of sql server, and that your user name and password are correct. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378526.aspx for more help.

Comment: via Eclipse environment everything is ok. Only this packed version has this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved the problem.
I installed the jdbc driver also on the remote server, and I packed the files to an executable jar (not only jar as before).